# Ember Data: delete child record from parent view

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have association as Offer has many items

On offer-show page, am displaying the details of all items that belongs to offer

Along with each item, am adding show link and destroy button.

Facing issue while implementing destroy of item

view: (offer-page)

```
    {{#each items}}
      <tr>
        <td><img {{bind-attr src=defaultImage }}></td>
        <td>{{this._data.name}}</td>
        <td>{{#link-to 'item' this}}Show{{/link-to}}</td>
        <td><button {{action 'removeItem' this.id}}>Remove</button></td>
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
```

offer controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['item'],

  actions: {
    removeItem: function(item) {
      //...what should i add here
    }
  }
});
```

item controller

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    remove: function() {
      var currentItem = this.get('model');
      var offer = currentItem.get('offerId');
      currentItem.destroyRecord().then(function() {
        router.transitionTo('offer', offer);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

routes

```
this.resource('offer', { path: '/:offer_id'}, function() {
  this.route('index', { path: '/'});
  this.resource('items', function(){
    this.resource('item', { path: ':item_id'}, function() {
      this.route('remove');
    });
  });
```

can anyone pls help me..how i can achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to above question..

Thanks to Matt Cudmore

http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-data-delete-child-record-from-parent-view/5953